# CFstart shows warning on "Apache Tomcat Native library"

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We I do a command line start of ColdFusion 10, I get the following warning

```
D:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\bin>cfstart
Oct 29, 2013 6:43:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performanc
e in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\\ColdFus
ion10\\cfusion\lib;D:\\ColdFusion10\\cfusion\jintegra\bin;D:\\ColdFusion10\\cfus
ion\jintegra\bin\international;D:\\ColdFusion10\\cfusion\lib\oosdk\classes\win
Oct 29, 2013 6:43:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
```

I am running the built in Server. What is needed to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the APR - http://apr.apache.org/
2. Follow the docs to install & configure - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html